# Composer repository type depends on environment

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to add repositories in my composer.json where the source depends on the application environment. For example, if I am in local environment, I want to include repositories from a local file path and if it is in production, then I want to include from GIT.

In local:

```
"repositories": [
     {
         "type": "path",
         "url": "../local-path"
     },
 ]
```

In production:

```
"repositories": [
     {
         "type": "vcs",
         "url": "https://github.com/...."
     },
 ]
```

In my .env file is an APP_ENV variable. Are there any possibilities to achive this?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? It sounds like you're going to run into tons of trouble this way. As soon as the repository on git diverts from the local version, your dev environment and production run different codebases, potentially leading to a situation where the local environment works while production is broken. My advice is to not solve this but find a better road towards your real goal. What *is* the real goal? What's the objection against using the github version everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this isn't a great idea because you have a risk of potentially committing your `composer.lock` file from the wrong environment and deploying it. Hopefully you have stricter deployment checks in place though!

I don't have an exact solution, but some options instead:

#### Use a Composer config file locally

- No need for separate composer file
- Might get finicky about versions (I've had trouble getting composer to symlink before)
- Should allow you to only maintain one `composer.json` and only touch the config file when you add new local repos

[Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home-config-json)

In this example I created a project with a simple `composer.json`.

```
{
    "name": "mickadoo/test",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "mickadoo/basedata": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I added a single requirement which is a package I put on packagist myself years ago.

I then created a dummy library to test it locally with the same name. It was in a `library` directory which contained only a `composer.json` file. The goal is to check if composer will install this empty library (no requirements) instead of the online one.

```
{
    "name": "mickadoo/basedata",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {}
}
```

I then added a `config.json` file to the project root with configuration telling composer to add a local repo one directory up:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../library"
    }
  ]
}
```

After all that I tried first running `composer update` and setting the `COMPOSER_HOME` env variable to my current directory. This ensures that composer will pick up the `config.json` and merge it into the configuration it's using.

```
$ COMPOSER_HOME=$PWD composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing mickadoo/basedata (dev-master): Symlinking from ../library
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I then deleted everything I did because I've messed around with local paths in composer before and know it can be frustrating to get working:

```
$ rm -rf vendor/ && rm composer.lock
```

Finally I tried just running `composer update` as normal, hoping it would skip the `config.json` and just pull the package from Github.

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 14 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.13.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.2): Downloading (100%)         
... more package installs from Github here....
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Which it did!

#### Use a separate `composer.json`

- Keeps things pretty visible
- Separate `composer.lock` file

[Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer)

This would mean maintaining two separate files, like `composer.local.json` and `composer.json`. It might be tedious, but at least it's clear what's going on. Based on your `COMPOSER` env variable you can change which filename it's using

Answer (score 1):

I see here a couple of options.

1. Use a local path to a repository. Then on the dev env checkout different one than on the production. But this would require to keep the local repository in sync with the remote.
2. Define dist and source for the repository and then differentiate it running composer commands (`--prefer-dist` on prod, `--prefer-source` on dev).
3. Build your own plugin https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md which would jump into action before certain events https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names
4. Another option would be to have `composer.json` file for production and `composer-dev.json` for development and run the second with setting system ENV variable first:

   `COMPOSER=composer-dev.json php composer install`

   But this can produce some incompatibility issues (when you forgot to move a package from `composer-dev.json` to production `composer.json`.